# For python's built-in sort()'s key parameter, when to use base class vs object as identifier?

Tags: python

Let me take an example to clarify what I am talking about.
Say I'm trying to `sort()` a `str`ing `s` with a `key` of `count` (frequency of letters) and in a different case, with a `key` of `lower`.
Now, for `count`, it is required that I use the variable (object) identifier `s` as follows

```py
"".join(sorted(s, key=s.count))
```

While, for `lower`, it is required that I use the base class identifier `str` as follows

```py
"".join(sorted(s, key=str.lower))
```

I want to understand why is the usage different in these two examples? And for other methods, how should I understand which identifier to use?

Comment: The key needs to accept exactly one argument.  So you could not use `str.count` nor `s.lower` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `key` parameter takes a function which takes a single argument which is an item in the list. For methods of a class like `str`, their methods have the signatures

```py
def count(self, x):
    ...
def lower(self):
    ...
```

In particular, the both have `self` as the first argument. If you create an instance of the class, the first argument is "bound" to that instance, which basically passes in that instance for `self` when you call it. Then, calling `s.count(x)` is the same as `str.count(s, x)`, and `str.lower(s)` passes in `s` as `self`, and it's the same as `s.lower()`.

For the sorting example, passing in `key=s.count` means you want to sort the string based on the number of times a character appears in the string. For each character `x` of `s`, it calls `s.count(x)`.

When `key=str.lower`, it sorts the string based on the lowercase value of each character, and it is the same as calling `x.lower()` for each character `x` in `s`.